# this.state value is not accessible in component method

Tags: reactjs

I am using ReactJS and  trying to set a value for baseUrl as below in the constructor:

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { baseUrl: '' }

        //get the api base url
        fetch('/AppSettings/GetSettings')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.state =({ baseUrl: JSON.stringify(data) });
            });
    }
```

But the value is not available in the method below in the same class/component:

```
 getAll(): Promise<StandardCostItem[]> {
        return fetch(this.baseUrl + '/StandardCostItem')
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<StandardCostItem[]>)
        .then(standardCostItems => Array.from(standardCostItems, c => new StandardCostItem(c)));
}
```

Please advise why the value is not being passed?

Best regards,
Mostafa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-setting `this.state` value is not going to work correctly with React. The state can be set only once in the constructor. To update the state, [`this.setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) should be used.

Comment: event this.setState does not work, in the function this.state.baseUrl is undefined

Comment: @Mostafa where are you using this value? If it's undefined, you're setting it to `undefined` value. Also, keep in mind that this action is async, therefore the first `render` call will not receive the updated state but the originally set value.

Comment: Your operation is asynchronous and you must use setState()  but I believe your undefined `this` is happening because there is different scope inside the fetch callback. Try `let self = this` before the fetch block and then use self.state inside of it.

Comment: @user2355058 the arrow function (`=>`) already takes care of binding `this` to the outside reference. If that weren't the case, the `this.setState(...)` would throw `Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function`.

Comment: @Marko the value is being assigned correctly in the constructor, but it is not available in the method (e.g. getAll)

Comment: @Mostafa when is the method `getAll` called? Keep in mind that the `fetch` function you're calling in the `constructor` is async and so is `setState` function. This means that even after calling `this.setState({x: 1})`, the immediate value of `this.state.x` won't be 1. The value will be updated after React executes state update and it will trigger a component update.